# unable to resolve class javassist.NotFoundException

Tags: hibernate, grails, classnotfoundexception, javassist

I have a grails applications and I uninstalled hibernate. When I compile exists an import that can't be resolved.

```
unable to resolve class javassist.NotFoundException
   import javassist.NotFoundException
```

This is an import that is used on a class.

Could you help me on how can I to fix this?

thanks!

Comment: Try to clean your project

Comment: I cleaned the project and still the problem :(